# How do you display the current date and time in Crystal Reports?

Tags: datetime, crystal-reports, formatting

How do you display the current date and time in Crystal Reports?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Create a new formula and use:

```
CurrentDateTime
```

This would display the following:

> 18.05.2015   2:28:46PM

Then you can format it using ToText:

```
ToText(CurrentDateTime, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
```

Which would display (same as first example's datetime) :

> 18/05/2015 14:28:46

Comment: Thanks @goamn, it works for me. You should mark this one as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add:

ToText(currentdatetime,"dd/M/yy hh:mm") will display as 8/2/17 04:26

where as

ToText(currentdatetime,"d/M/yy HH:mm") will display as 8/2/17 16:26

(For those who would like to change the time to a 24 hour format)

Answer (score 0):

`CurrentDateTime` will return `dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss`

if you want to display the date without any Delimiter and not in datetime, then `TONUMBER(ToText(CurrentDateTime,"yyMMdd"))` will return `yyMMdd`

[datetime][crystalreport]